# VMware ESXi: Connect to VM serial using named pipe

Tags: vmware-esxi

I'm running Linux VM guest on VMware ESXi 5.1 host. The guest has only serial tty. The only way to interact with it seems to be serial over named pipe. 
I've added serial port to the VM, assigning pipe name, near end=server and far end=process.
I expected that some named pipe should be created on vmware host and I will be able to connect somehow...
Nothing is created however (tried find ./ -name pipename).

How can I connect to the named pipe, is it created?

( there are also other options for serial port: readonly "output file" and "use network" not available in free ESXi)

Comment: Yeah, this is a weird situation. More details, please!

Answer (score 1):

> The guest has only serial tty

Why? Linux VM guests normally have at least one vNIC and the console - even with the free version - I don't see what you're trying to achieve here, can you explain why you can't just do this?

Named pipes, or serial for that matter, are really not the usual mechanism for accessing VMs.

Have you had any form of VMWare training or experience?